# How to kill Java.exe from a Windows Batch File?

Tags: windows, java, batch-file

How do I write a batch file script which will kill the java.exe process? I intend to run it from the Windows Task Scheduler.

Thanks.

Comment: what version of windows are you using?

Comment: google "[schedule a batch file](https://www.google.com/search?q=schedule+a+batch+file&aq=f&oq=schedule+a+batch+file&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.4474&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" and it gives plenty of options for finding out how. You could even append your version of windows, whether it is [Windows XP](http://tinyurl.com/aj2w35w), [Windows 7](http://tinyurl.com/akzjtzl), or [Windows 8](http://tinyurl.com/a5zkjfg) and get results specific to your OS.

Answer (score 6):

```
taskkill.exe /IM java.exe
```

or if you want to force the process to exit use:

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM java.exe
```

Comment: Can you please little bit more elaborate how i make it in notepad bat job and then run it in task schedule.

Comment: This will kill all java processes.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to follow this implementation

> taskkill /F (force) /IM (the next value is the imageName) programName.exe (and the image name!)

So I would use

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

[More reading](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: +1 for posting this faster than me ;)

Comment: only by 16 seconds!

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. so its mean i should copy the exect lines. (taskkill /F /IM java.exe) and save the notepad file with kill.bat and then run it through task schedule .it will run ?

Comment: yes. either place it in a batch file (using notepad as you described) or directly execute the command from the taskscheduler

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
wmic process where name="java.exe" delete
```

Or:

```
tskill java /a
```

Comment: kindly note that i need a BATCH job file which i will run through Task Schedule. How can i do that ?

Comment: kindly note that there are HUNDREDS of tutorials for writing batch files. Here's a quick one: 1) Open Notepad. 2) Paste the line `taskkill /f /im java.exe` to Notepad. 3) Save the file as `"kill-java.cmd"`.

Answer (score 0):

Force kill java.exe as Admin...

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM java.exe
```

And delete caches...

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.gradle\caches
```